# ASP.NET declaring array of Controls in CodeBehind not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello
I need to group some Dropdown lists in ASP.NET form.So I wanted to create an array of DLs at the instance level as below in the code behind file.

```
DropDownList[] dls = { Dl1, Dl2, Dl3 };
```

where Dl1 etc are DropDown Lists on my form. So I get an error "A field initializer cannot reference a non static field method or property". However if I move the code inside a function it works OK. But I need to create it at instance level so multiple methods can use it.

Any Ideas about the best way to handle this.

Comment: Put it in the constructor.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyPage : Page {

    DropDownList[] dls;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dls = new []{ Dl1, Dl2, Dl3 };
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: Yours is the long form syntax, but josephj1989's is the same thing.

Comment: Your second version is an intermediately short syntax - the question author is using the shortest possible c# syntax. (Oops, fyi - this is in response to the deleted comment)

Comment: @John ya I realized that. The other thing was that I didn't read the question fully. I have edited the answer now.

Comment: +1 (voted changed) BTW, I prefer using the ASP.NET event handlers too, instead of ctor, for control-related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could get it to work.  Credit to [slugster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) for the idea:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DropDownList[] dls = null;

    public _Default()
    { 
        dls = new DropDownList[] { dl1, dl2, dl3 };
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
    }
}
```